# Determining the rank, nullspace and image of a matrix with one unknown

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the matrix:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}x &0&2&2 \\-2&2&-2&2\\2&2&-2&2\\2&0&2&-2 \end{pmatrix}$$

Determine $\text{rank(A)}$ as well as a basis for the nullspace and image of $A$.

My attempt:

$$\text{ref}(A)=\begin{pmatrix}-2 &2&-2&2 \\0&4&-4&4\\0&0&2&2\\0&0&0&-4 \end{pmatrix}$$

Since $\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(\text{ref}(A)) \implies \text{rank}(A)=4$

$$\implies \text{dim}(\text{im(A)})=4 \\ \implies \text{dim}(\text{null(A)})=0$$

Therefore a basis for the image could just be my column vectors of $A$ and a basis for the nullspace would be $(0,0,0,0)^T$. Would that be correct? Also, it seems like the rank, nullspace and image are totally independent of $x$. This is a bit puzzling since the question on my problem set specifically askas how they depend on $x$. Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit 1:** Here are the row operations I performed:

$$\begin{pmatrix}x &0&2&2 \\-2&2&-2&2\\2&2&-2&2\\2&0&2&-2 \end{pmatrix}\xrightarrow{R_2 \leftrightarrow R_1} \begin{pmatrix}-2 &2&-2&2 \\x&0&2&2\\2&2&-2&2\\2&0&2&-2 \end{pmatrix}\xrightarrow{R_2-\frac{x}{2}R_3} \begin{pmatrix}-2 &2&-2&2 \\0&-x&2+x&2-x\\2&2&-2&2\\2&0&2&-2 \end{pmatrix} \\ \xrightarrow{R_3+R1, R_4+R_1} \begin{pmatrix}-2 &2&-2&2 \\0&-x&2+x&2-x\\0&4&-4&4\\0&2&0&0 \end{pmatrix} \xrightarrow{R_3 \leftrightarrow R_2} \begin{pmatrix}-2 &2&-2&2 \\0&4&-4&4\\0&-x&2+x&2-x\\0&2&0&0 \end{pmatrix} \\ \xrightarrow{R_3+\frac{x}{4}R_2} \begin{pmatrix}-2 &2&-2&2 \\0&4&-4&4\\0&0&2&2\\0&2&0&0 \end{pmatrix} \xrightarrow{R_4-\frac{1}{2}R_2} \begin{pmatrix}-2 &2&-2&2 \\0&4&-4&4\\0&0&2&2\\0&&2&-2 \end{pmatrix} \xrightarrow{R_4-R_3} \begin{pmatrix}-2 &2&-2&2 \\0&4&-4&4\\0&0&2&2\\0&0&0&-4 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: This isn't reduced row echelon form. If you simplify it, you will find that you end up getting the identity matrix as your reduced echelon form. The takeaway should be that the rank, nullspace, and image are independent of x in this case.

Comment: @JackMoody I meant to say row echelon form. But I am glad I got it somewhat right when saying it is independent of $x$. Thanks for your help

Comment: I would say that all you have done is OK to me.

Comment: Where did $x$ go in  your echelon form?

Comment: @Bernard I swapped the first row with the second row and then performed row operations. I checked my answer with matrixcalc.org and there the determinant and rank were also independent of $x$. Do you want me to include the row operations in my post? Maybe I did something wrong. Are you getting a different result?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the $4\times4$ determinant has a $x+2$ factor, hence the rank should be  $\le 3$ for $x=-2$. However I made the computation by hand, so I should check it.

Comment: I have an error: Maxima says the determinant is $64$.

Comment: @Bernard I also get 64 as the determinant. I edited my question and added the row operations I performed. "$x$" just cancels and I am left with a matrix with no unknown. As far as I know that also implies that my rank, image and nullspace are not dependent on $x$.

Comment: Absolutely${}$.

Comment: @Bernard Great! Just out of curiosity, would computing the determinant (and getting a result independent of $x$) have been enough to show that the rank, nullspace and image are also not dependent on $x$?

Comment: Yes: if the determinant is not $0$, the kernel is $\{0\}$, and the image is the whole space, since we have the matrix of a bijection (more precisely an isomorphism).

Comment: @Bernard Cool! Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. It's a pleasure to help!